# What is the minimum visit time duration that would trigger a Visit Monitoring call on iOS?

Tags: ios, gps, ios8, location

iOS 8 introduces a Visit Monitoring API which I plan to use.  My use case: if a user visits a location that exists in my backend database, I will show a notification with some useful info about the place.

I plan to implement the locationManager didVisit method. How long does a visit need to be before didVisit is called?  If it is longer than 15-20 minutes, it may not work because I don't expect user to stay for very long.